# Cropping Image View inside circle in iOS -- corners still showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, geometry, cornerradius

I have a UITableViewCell with an Image View inside of it, and I would like to crop the image to a circle. I currently have the following in the cell's initialization:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code

    //make profile image circular
    self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;   
}
```

However, the image ends up looking like

[image: this].

How do I get this to look like a circle? The image looks more rounded if I make the corner radius smaller, but everyone seems to recommend width/2.

Comment: is the source image squared?

Comment: It's not an answer but I recommend not to use layer modification on UITableViewCell. It makes tableView's scroll slow. Make transparent .png and add on your own image.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, The source image is square.

Comment: Check profileImage width and height, both should be equal otherwise you can't get full circle. And I suggest pre rendered images, doing too much layer mods in tableview could cause performance issues.

Comment: What happens if you typed static values for your cornerRadius rather than using a formula, say your photo is 100 x 100 pixels, if you typed  cornerRadius = 100.0 / 2.0; Can you log your actual width and height of your image frame?

Comment: use masking of image with circle.. it is better than croping image..